# smbclient - Send all files in directory

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I created a shell script to send files on Linux to Windows via sbmclient.

```
smbclient //HOST_WINDOWS/D$ -U USER --pass PASSWORD -c "put /tmp/test.txt FOLDER_WINDOWS/test.txt"
```

That works perfectly.

```
smbclient //HOST_WINDOWS/D$ -U USER --pass PASSWORD -c "put /tmp/* FOLDER_WINDOWS"
```

I would like to send all files at once, is it possible?

Answer (score 28):

I found that it only works reliably when the local working directory is equal to the directory that you want to upload.

But it's possible to specify a local directory:

```
smbclient //HOST_WINDOWS/D$ -W domain -U username \
-c 'prompt OFF; recurse ON; cd remote/target/directory; lcd /local/source/directory; mput *'
```

In interactive mode I guess that would look something like this:

```
smb: \folder\> recurse ON
smb: \folder\> prompt OFF
smb: \folder\> lcd /local/source/directory
smb: \folder\> cd remote/target/directory
smb: \folder\> mput *
```

Answer (score 4):

Connect with smbclient '//host/folder' -U user --pass Password.

Once connected type the following:

```
smb: \folder\> recurse
smb: \folder\> prompt
smb: \folder\> mput NameOfDirectoryToBeCopiedToSMBHostFolder*
```

**Note:**  Don't forget the * at the end of the directory name.