# Sending files to smb server

Tags: samba

I've got a server with an smb address, `smb://files.cluster.ins.localnet/`
Is it possible to send there files (fast) via the command line in a way similar to `scp` or `rsync`?

For example,

```
scp_to_samba folder_to_copy smb://files.cluster.ins.localnet/copied_content_folder/
```

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a way to get either `rsync` or `scp` to play nice with Samba servers. Try using using `smbclient -c` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46096270):

```
smbclient //files.cluster.ins.localnet -c 'prompt OFF; recurse ON; lcd folder_to_copy; mkdir copied_content_folder; cd copied_content_folder; mput *'
```

If you're planning on communicating with the same server frequently and want something command-like, you could try something like this bash 'script':

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# scp_to_samba.sh

smbclient //files.cluster.ins.localnet -W domain -U username \
-c "prompt OFF; recurse ON; lcd $1; mkdir $2; cd $2; mput *"
```

where `domain` and `username` are whatever credentials you need to log on to your server. Usage would then be:

```
./scp_to_samba.sh folder_to_copy copied_content_folder
```

To copy back from the server, you'd need to switch a few things in that command/script and use `mget` instead of `mput`.

Is this 'fast'? I don't know. But it is pretty straightforward and has worked pretty well for me so far.

See the [smbclient man page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbclient.1.html) for more details.